# executing a filter (breadth-first) on a tree - javascript

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I wrote the following function to apply a filter to a Tree (using breadth-first search). I wanted to add the children of any given element to the queue, but ran into issues when doing it outside the while loop below. Is there any way I could have done the adding of the child trees (to the queue) outside the while loop?

```
Tree.prototype.BFSelect = function (filter) {
  var queue = new Queue();
  var results = [];
  //push the root onto the queue.
  queue.push({
    tree: this,
    depth: 0
  });

  //check the queue and filter it.
  while (item = queue.pop()) {
    tree = item.tree;
    depth = item.depth;

    if(filter(tree.value, depth)) {
      results.push(tree.value);
    }
    //why does depth = undefined outside the while loop? doesn't make sense to do it here.
    for(var i = 0; i<tree.children.length; i++) {
      child = tree.children[i];
      queue.push({tree: child, depth: depth + 1});
    }
  }

  return results;
};
```

Comment: Nope.  Why do you want to push the children outside the loop?

Comment: Also, you wrote a DFS. for a BFS you want item = queue.shift()

Comment: should have clarified that - the queue.pop() function uses .shift() in my implementation

Comment: I was thinking that since we are pushing the root to the queue outside the while loop, why not just push all of it's children there as well? why do we need to do that when removing from the queue?

Comment: the queue is the queue of nodes that will be processed by the loop.  You need the children to be processed by the loop, so you have to push them before the loop is finished.  You don't discover them until after the loop has started, so...  you must have to push them inside the loop.